# Confusion with notation for Dirichlet characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, analytic-number-theory, characters, dirichlet-character

While I have understood the properties of Dirichlet characters and how to construct tables for them, I am incredibly confused by the notation. Here are the notations in use in the book *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* (Tom M. Apostol), Theorem 6.14.

> **Definition** Dirichlet characters. Let $G$ be the group of reduced residue classes modulo $k$. Corresponding to each character $f$ of $G$ we define an arithmetical function $\chi = \chi_f$ as follows:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \chi(n) & = f(\hat{n}) & \text{ if } (n, k) = 1, \\
> \chi(n) & = 0 & \text{ if } (n, k) > 1.
> \end{align*}
> The function $\chi$ is called a Dirichlet character modulo $k$. The principal character $\chi_1$ is what which has the properties
> $$ \chi_1(n) = \begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{ if } (n, k) = 1, \\
> 0 & \text{ if } (n, k) > 1.
> \end{cases} $$

But previously, in section 6.6, the principal character of a group $G$ was denoted by $f_1$ and the others denoted by $f_2$, $f_3$, $\dots$. So if we choose the principal character $f_1$ and find the corresponding principal Dirichlet character, should it not be denoted as $\chi_{f_1}$? Is $\chi_1$ simply a shorthand for $\chi_{f_1}$?

In that case, is this a more accurate way of defining the notation for Dirichlet characters?

- Corresponding to each character $f_i$ of $G$ we define an arithmetical function $\chi_i$ as follows: \begin{align*}
  \chi_i(n) & = f_i(\hat{n}) & \text{ if } (n, k) = 1, \\
  \chi_i(n) & = 0 & \text{ if } (n, k) > 1.
  \end{align*}
- Then use $\chi_i(n)$ notation everywhere and don't use $\chi(n)$ anywhere? Why is the secondary notation $\chi(n)$ useful?

Comment: Yes, $\chi_1$ is a shorthand for $\chi_{f_1}$. The principal character is an exception in many ways, so it makes sense to have a particular symbol for it; but there is no canonical order on the other characters (either group characters or Dirichlet characters), so it turns out not to be useful to name them $\chi_2,\chi_3,\dots$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! And similarly, $\chi_{i}$ is a shorthand for $\chi_{f_i}$? I understand there is no canonical order for the characters $f_i$ and thus the Dirichlet characters $\chi_{i}$. Just want to be sure that these all $\chi_{i}$ notations are shorthands for $\chi_{f_i}$. While constructing tables, the book makes heavy use of notations $\chi_2$, $\chi_3$, $\dots$ .

Comment: That notation seems ridiculous. If $\chi$ is a character mod $k$, defined at first on the invertible numbers mod $k$, just extend $\chi$ to all integers mod $k$ by declaring it to be $0$ on the noninvertible numbers mod $k$. (That keeps the character totally multiplicative.) Nobody in the real world is so fussy about “$f$” vs. “$\chi$.” Just write all characters mod $k$ as $\chi$. His “$f$” notation is weird. It should be obvious in context what is meant (e.g., are characters viewed as functions on integers mod $k$ or as functions on integers),  and if not just clarify with ordinary words.